# Export to swf image to pdf or png

Tags: actionscript-3, pdf, adobe, flash

I made a simple certificate maker application using Adobe Flash & action script for calculations, that has 2 frames which takes input from user, eg. on frame1, it takes basic information like name, address, phone number etc. then user click **next** button to navigate on 2nd frame, then it takes some numerical data, like marks in some subjects for first, second and third terminal examinations and again pressing the next button navigates the user to 3rd frame which shows the final certificate after some calculations on numerical data to calculate grades and cumulative percentages. Since this is an swf movie, I right click on the final result and print it.. There is no mechanism to save it for future re-printing/viewing (read-only). I was thinking to give a button for save that could convert the final output with a background image & some dynamic fields to pdf or png. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AlivePDF, you can find it here: 
http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/
Example code how to use it can be viewed here
http://snipplr.com/view/45819/